# Update final fields only if not null in constructor dart

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a class called App with some fields.
I want to initalize the final fields only if passed parameters to constructor are not null.

e.g in below code I want to set config param only if it is not null.

I tried below code but it is not working

```
@immutable
class App {
    final AuthState auth;
    final RConfig config;

    App({AuthState auth, this.config}):
        auth = auth ?? new AuthState(), config = config != null ? config : this.config ;
```

Although I am quite new to dart, I know that I can't initalize final fields twice but there are app states due to which AppState get created again and RConfig may be null at that time.

My question is as simple is this how to check multiple final fields validity e.g null or empty before assigning them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize a field twice. You initialize `config` both with an initializing formal (`this.config`) and an initializer list entry `config = ...`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `config`, but start by declaring it as a normal parameter, then figure out what you want to do:

```
AppState({AuthState auth, RConfig config})
    : auth = auth ?? new AuthState(), config = config; // or something
```

Comment: I'm not generally familiar with optional annotations, they have no effect on the behavior of the program (they can make tools give you extra warnings, but the meaning of the program doesn't change). I don't think the `Immutable` annotation makes any difference - the code I gave above works, if you need something else, you need to figure out what that is.

Comment: or it's even easier to define a default value to your optional parameter: `AppState({AuthState auth = AuthState.dummy(), RConfig config}){...}`